# Nuxt auth without the user endpoint

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt auth, but I don't have an endpoint for the user, in nuxt.config is set the endpoint to be false and after loginWith I'm jest setting the user manually.

The issue is that **after refresh I'm logged in but I don't have any user info** (name, email...) what I'm I missing here?

nuxt.config file:

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/users/login/',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token',
          },
          logout: { url: '/api/users/logout/', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/api/users/auth/', method: 'post' },
          // user: false,
        },
        autoFetchUser: false,
        tokenName: 'Authorization',
        tokenType: 'Token',
        // tokenRequired: true,
        // globalToken: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

login form file

```
     const { data } = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
          data: { username: this.email, password: this.password },
        });
        this.$auth.setUser(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you logged in, user info will return from login data, when you refresh there is no endpoint for user, then auth plugin cant retrieve your user info, so you must do it manually and `setUser` yourself

Comment: thank you.
let's say I've save it in localStorage where do I ````setUser```` manually on refresh? I tried to do it with ````created````  in the defeultt.vue file but I gut a diff between my server and client now.

Comment: Set data before mount will cause mismatch between server and client, also layouts dont have access `asyncData` and `fetch`, in this case you should use `context.$auth.setUser` in `nuxtServerInit`